# Problems in ExtJS with method getGroups

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use an Ext JS 4. The controller User load several tabs of the same model. The name of each tab to be in the column "group". Tab with the name "default" is standard. Here is some code from the controller:

```
onLaunch: function(app) {
    var self = this;
    this.getUserStore().on("load", function(store) {
        var groups = store.getGroups();

        for (tab in self.tabs)
            try
            {
                Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#mainLayout")[0].remove(self.tabs[tab], true);
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                if (console)
                    console.log(err, "Happened, but it's okay");
            }

        self.tabs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {

            if (groups[i].name == "default")
                continue;

            var newStore = Ext.create("al.store.User2");

            newStore.loadRecords(groups[i].children);

            var id = "tab-id-" + groups[i].name;

            try
            {

                Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#mainLayout")[0].add({
                    xtype: 'userlist',
                    title: groups[i].name,
                    id: id,
                    store: newStore
                });
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                alert(err);
            }


            self.tabs.push(id);

        }

        store.clearFilter(true);
        store.filter([{id: "class", property: "group", value: "default"}]);
    });
},

refresh: function() {
    this.getUserStore().load();
},
```

The problem is that when you first load everything works fine, but when the user tries to update a tab (method "refresh"), lost all tabs except the standard. Problem in method "store.getGroups()". This method working normal in the first load, but when user tries to update a tab this method give 0 groups. How to solve this problem?

Comment: where is refresh function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's because of `filter`. In the end of `load` handler you set the filter, which is set to show only *default* group.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am newbie in ExtJS, in the next time I will be more attentive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the second time you load the store it fetches no data. Verify that the request is valid (contains (all eventual) parameters) and that request returns data.

Hope it helps:)

ps.

If it is not the case, show me store, model and exemplary request with response data.

ps2.

One more thing - what is it you describe as "tab"? I do not understand "tab of model".